# Pass mocked API object to rails controller during test

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, tdd, minitest

My question is regarding testing (MiniTest) a Rails 4.0 controller which queries an API. So for instance, I have this controller:

```
class InsolentController

    def show 

        @result = SomeApi.get value1, value2

    end

end
```

Now I want to test it without calling my API, so if I were using ASP.NET MVC I could do something like this:

```
public Class InsolentController
{
    private SomeAPI someApi;

    public InsolentController(SomeAPI api = null)
    {

        this.someApi = api ?? new SomeAPI();
    }

    public ActionResult Show()
    {
        var result = this.someApi.Get(value1, value2);

        // return, etc...
    }
}
```

I do this so that I can mock SomeAPI. So how do I go about this when I want to use MiniTest with rails, for example:

```
require 'test_helper'

class InsolentControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

    test "should get show" do

        get :show, { value1: 10, value2: 34 }

        assert_response :success
    end

end
```

Comment: I'm looking at a similar problem, did you ever figure this out ?

Comment: Hi Tom, No I did not. I was just toying with the Rails framework anyway so it wasn't a big deal, but perhaps it will help someone along the way. Good on you that you figured it out based on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [rspec-mocks](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/outside-rspec/integrate-with-minitest) and setting it up with minitest.

You should easily be able to do something like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class InsolentControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "should get show" do
    value1 = 10
    value2 = 34
    expect(SomeApi).to receive(:get).with(value1, value2)

    get :show, { value1: value1, value2: value2 }
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```